# SQL INSERT with multiple rows of values using Jython and zxJDBC

Tags: python, sql, database, prepared-statement, jython

I'm programming in Jython to an SQL database, using the `com.ziclix.python.sql` package. I'm wondering if the package has support in its prepared statements for SQL INSERT/UPDATE statements where you pass multiple rows of values rather than just one row, so that you're inserting multiple rows in one INSERT statement. Let me explain.

Here's a basic SQL INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO Names (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ("John", "Doe");
```

Using the zxJDBC prepared statement, this is pretty trivial:

```
# Assume cursor object
statement = 'INSERT INTO Names (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (?, ?)'
cursor.execute(statement, ('John', 'Doe'))
```

But the kind of INSERT statement I'm interested in is where you insert multiple rows of values, like so:

```
INSERT INTO Names (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ("John", "Doe"), ("Mary", "Smith");
```

Is there some way to do this using prepared statements? I would rather use prepared statements to build up an SQL query rather than string interpolation, if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldnt do it in a loop?  What about a insert with a select?

Comment: I can do it in a loop, but my understanding is that each call to cursor.execute represents a separate round trip to the database. In testing I'm doing 100 rows at a time, but in production it will likely be much, much higher than that. Inserting multiple values in one call to cursor.execute seems like an optimization I can't do without, since if I understand correctly, that will be only one round trip to the database.

Comment: You are correct about trips to the database.  Still, you would want to get a sense of exactly how slow it will be for you.  You can write some awful code if try to optimise in a place you dont need to

Comment: If you are creating the sql as your question indicates, by interpolating the data, you could create a union that would allow you to insert multiple rows.

Comment: I have tested inserting 10,000 rows. Using either cursor.execute or cursor.executemany takes 16.25 seconds. Using a hand-built statement (with string interpolation) where I'm inserting multiple rows on one trip takes 0.05 seconds. 10,000 rows is what is likely in production.

As to creating a union, can you expand on that? That's something I haven't done in SQL. Are you sure that's feasible for what I want to do? Thanks.

Comment: Feedback?  Can you see how my answer can work for you?

Comment: I do see how it can work, though I discussed it with a colleague, and we don't see how building up the string using unions has any advantage to building up the string using multiple sets of values.

Comment: You are correct, it is little different from the multiple sets of values.  Still, a prepared statement is just string interpolation.  Probably what you really want is some kind of lazy execution, but I'm not sure how to do that other than manually building the string as we've discussed.  Too bad you're not using c# and Linq. :)  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since zxJDBC implements [PEP 249](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) " Python Database API Specification v2.0", you can use the method executemany() to accomplish this:

```
# Assume cursor object
statement = 'INSERT INTO Names (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (?, ?)'
cursor.executemany(statement, (
    ('John', 'Doe'),
    ('Mary', 'Smith'),
    # ...
    )
)
```

**Update**: Looks like this is too slow, since zxJDBC just calls execute many times without optimising the query. Instead you could do:

```
from itertools import chain
statement = 'INSERT INTO Names (FirstName, LastName) VALUES {values}'.format(
    values = ','.join('(?, ?)' for _ in input_seq))
input_seq = (
    ('John', 'Doe'),
    ('Mary', 'Smith'),
    # ...
    )
cursor.execute(statement, list(chain(*input_seq)))
```

This *does* involve some string manipulation, but it preserves the use of parameter lists and allows a single DB round-trip.

Comment: From what I can tell, cursor.executemany is a convenience to the programmer, but still makes individual round trips to the database. See what I wrote above in a comment to paqogomez. I tested inserting 10,000 rows, which is the kind of load my application will have in production. executemany is no faster than execute -- 16.25 seconds (on my machine). If I do a bit of string concatenation and execute it all at once, it takes 0.05 seconds. That's 325 times faster. Cobbling together the strings however requires tweaking the data a bit, while a prepared statement saves me all that trouble.

Comment: You know what, I realize that what I'm asking for now is not what I asked for at the outset. I said nothing about optimization until after I started getting some answers. If you know of any, please let me know. But, I feel like I should mark yours as the correct answer.

Comment: Yep, [it looks like you're right](https://bitbucket.org/jython/jython/src/6e438088c0e3e624465cc0747761650da3eb280f/src/com/ziclix/python/sql/PyCursor.java?at=default#cl-507). I have an idea for a hacky way to get what you want though...

Comment: I marked your answer as the correct one, because, like I said, it answered the question I asked. Thank you. As for the "hacky way," I already came up with a hacky way of my own. I build the values portion of my SQL statement dynamically, with multiple sets of values (each set enclosed in parentheses and separated from the set following it with a comma, per SQL syntax). That's working nicely. I was just hoping the module itself offered this. It's a bit tricky to convert the Python objects to how they should appear in a line of SQL. (Whereas, a prepared statement takes care of all this for you.)

Comment: P.S. I didn't see your update with the itertools. I'll take a look at that. Thanks!